# R - How to Read in a .fwf that contains a # sign

Tags: r, read.fwf

I am attempting to read in a large fixed width file into R using read.fwf, but I keep getting the error "Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 47 did not have 41 elements".  My dataset has 41 columns but when I read in line 48 alone I only get 27 columns.  I noticed that the error takes place when it encounters a # sign.  How can I either remove the # sign or force read.fwf to ignore it.  Here is a little of my code, but since the dataset is massive I am not going to provide it.

```
df <- read.fwf("flat404.DALLASCOUNTY.20161030.412476", widths = width2, col.names = fields)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use `comment.char = ""`

Comment: That did it. I saw that in the documentation, but thought it was the default and therefore unnecessary.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: The idea is to set the `comment.char` to character other than `#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the `comment.char` argument to blanks or a character that is not a `#`

```
df <- read.fwf("flat404.DALLASCOUNTY.20161030.412476", 
         widths = width2, col.names = fields, comment.char = "")
```